# Android - Scheduling Local Notifications on PhoneGap Build / Apache Cordova 4.1.1

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, phonegap-build, localnotification

I'm having issues trying to schedule local notifications on an Android app (using PhoneGap build).

I'm trying to schedule a local notification at a set date and time (e.g. September 23rd 2016 at 12:00pm).

I've tried using the following plugin:

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/2081

My config.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id          = "****"
    versionCode = "292000" 
    version     = "2.9.2" >

    <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
 <application android:debuggable="true" />
</gap:config-file>

<!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

<name>****</name>

<description>
   ****
</description>

<author href="****" email="****">
    ****
</author>

<icon src="icon.png" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="*" />

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23"/>

<gap:plugin name='cordova-plugin-whitelist' source='npm' />

<plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" spec="0.8.1" source="pgb" />

</widget>
```

I then schedule the notification using the code below:

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    title: $title,
    text: $message,
    at: $date
});
```

When building for the latest PhoneGap version (cli-6.3.0), I get the following error on the build.phonegap.com site:

> Error - Some official plugins have to be updated if using PhoneGap >= 4.0.0. Please upgrade the version of any plugins that may include the following file: LocalNotification.java

It seems that the plugin has not been updated for the latest version of PhoneGap causing the build to fail.

I've tried building for the latest supported version of the plugin (PhoneGap 3.7.0). The build completes successfully and when installed directly on an Android device, everything works correctly. The notifications fire as scheduled.

However, when trying to submit this build to the Google Play store, the build is rejected with the following error:

> Your APK has been rejected for containing security vulnerabilities, which violates the Malicious Behavior policy. The Alerts page has more information about how to resolve the issue. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.

The build now needs to use v4.1.1 of Apache Cordova to be accepted by the Google Play .

I've looked around but can't find a solution anywhere. Is anyone aware of a fix, or alternatively, a different plugin that allows scheduling of local notifications on Android supporting Apache Cordova v4.1.1 or above?

Comment: @RaGu Check out the basic local notification working sample in the following link - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Local_Notification hope it should help you get started

Comment: Check out the basic local notification working sample in the following link - github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Local_Notification hope it should help you get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<gap:plugin name='cordova-plugin-whitelist' source='npm' />

<plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" spec="0.8.1" source="pgb" />
```

to

```
<plugin name='cordova-plugin-whitelist' source='npm' />

<plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" spec="0.8.4" source="npm" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed myself.

Changing the plugin name will work.

We need to find an appropriate plugin and replace older version in config.xml.

In my case, I have changed

```
<plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" spec="0.8.4" source="pgb" />
```

to

```
<gap:plugin name="trunk.plugin.local-notification" />
```